# Reading multiple variable types from text file C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm attempting to read from a text file that looks like this

```
bend 6 7
fairbanks 3 5
```

and repeats line by line. The contents are always the same format, so string, then int, then int.

I'm trying to use stringstream to get each line of the file and then separate it from there. However, it doesn't appear to be reading anything at all. Here's my current attempt:

```
ifstream infile;
string line, cityName;
int xCoor, yCoor;
City* temp;

infile.open(filename);
while(getline(infile, line))
{
    istringstream iss(line, istringstream::in);

    iss >> cityName;
    while(iss >> xCoor >> yCoor)
    {
        temp = new City(cityName, xCoor, yCoor);
        addCity(temp);
    }
}
```

The function is passed a filename and gathers the name of a city, its x and y coordinates, makes a new City object, and then adds that city to a vector.

Am I misusing stringstream or is it just not a good way to go about solving this problem?

EDIT:

Here's the Map class

```
class Map {
    friend class City;
private:
    std::vector<City*> graph;
    void addCity(City* c) { graph.push_back(c); }
    City* findByNamePrivate(std::string cityName);
public:
    Map(std::string filename);
    City* findByName(std::string cityName) { return findByNamePrivate(cityName); }
};
```

The constructor for Map is what I'm having issues with.

Thought I had included this as well, but I guess not.

```
City* Map::findByNamePrivate(string cityName)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++)
    {
        if(graph[i]->getName() == cityName)
        {
            return graph[i];
        }
    }
}
```

The program fails when this line is called elsewhere

```
assert(map.findByName("bend") != NULL);
```

Comment: You should check the state after `infile.open(filename);`. Are you sure that the filename provided points to an accessible file path from your current working directory?

Comment: Looks ok, except that you don't check the result of `open`. Are you sure the `filename` names the file properly, and finds it in its directory?

Comment: @John, also check if you have a proper rights to read the file.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I just tried putting a simple print statement inside the first while loop and it didn't print, while putting one outside of it worked fine. So, the loop isn't running at all I guess?

Comment: Which points to the file not being read. My guess is you put it in the wrong folder for your IDE. If this is Visual Studio the default folder is the one containing the project file ( unless you changed the default setting in the debugger options for your project). Some other IDEs default to the location of the executable.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm not using an IDE, just a text editor and cygwin. Also, I don't think it's being read at all.

Comment: So then did you put the text file in the same folder as the executable file you created? I assume you are running the executable from a cygwin terminal and not directly from the text editor?

Comment: I hope your city names are always of one word (like New_York not "New York") otherwise you have a problem.

Comment: @Bob__ It is, don't worry.

Comment: `friend class City;`... so you can use the member variable which store the name directly in `findByNamePrivate` (just in case `getName` is doing something wrong) and maybe add a `return nullptr;` outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand why do you use loop while(iss>>xCoord >> yCoord) if you wrote "The contents are always the same format, so string, then int, then int". For your format you can simplify your read procedure:

```
while(infile >> cityName >> xCoor >> yCoor ) {
    addCity(new City(cityName, xCoor, yCoor));
}
```

Comment: It's a string, int, int, then new line. Wouldn't that not work with several lines?

Comment: It doesn't use `getline()` or is it supposed to replace the second while loop?

Comment: @John: you can use this code block instead of your code to read from file.

Comment: I just tried replacing everything with that and it still doesn't work. I'm honestly really lost now

Comment: @John: first of all you have to check that file is opened: if( infile ) {...} else {std::cerr << "Cannot open file" << std::endl;}

Comment: ***I just tried replacing everything with that and it still doesn't work.*** That is expected since the file is not being opened.

Comment: Adding error checking will not make it work but that isn't the point. The point is to help you debug the error and to make a well formed program by informing the user of the program that the file can not be open / found.

Comment: You're definitely right in that regard. The cerr does not print, which is a little concerning.

Comment: With all this said are you using aVast antivirus? If so disable it. aVast is known to prevent you from executing unknown compiled code (which anything you write will be).

Comment: Nope, no antivirus is installed.

Comment: @John: ok, file is opened, but program does not work. can you set break point to the addCity(new City(cityName, xCoor, yCoor)) line? can you show whole program?

Comment: @John well, the relevant code could be `findByNamePrivate()` too.